# 403 Error from Nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm running an Ubuntu 18.10 server running Nginx as installed from the Ubuntu repository.  When I try to reach the web server, though, I get a 403 error from Nginx.  I'm sure there's a simple fix, but I'm too green to know it.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

**403 Forbidden** is not an error code, but a HTTP status code. It is usually caused by an incorrect Index file or incorrect permissions. You should check nginx's error log file for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Turns out for some unknown reason my web root is different than I thought it was, at least according to the error log.  So now I need to figure out a)  why my web root isn't what I thought it was and b)  why I keep getting a 502 message when I try to access info.php.